# Why doesn't Tensorflow Bidirectional LSTM Match Forward and Backward LSTM?

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

In Tensorflow 2.x, the default merge_mode in Bidirectional layer is `concat`, as shown below.

```
tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(
    layer, merge_mode='concat', weights=None, backward_layer=None, **kwargs
)
```

**But, why `fb_out` is not a concatenation of `f_out` and `b_out` as shown in below test code?**

```
>>> import copy
>>> inputs = tf.random.normal([1, 5, 10])
>>> forward_layer = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True)
>>>
>>> backward_layer = LSTM(1, return_sequences=True, go_backwards=True)
>>>
>>> f_copy = copy.deepcopy(forward_layer)
>>>
>>> b_copy = copy.deepcopy(backward_layer)
>>>
>>> fb = Bidirectional(forward_layer, backward_layer=backward_layer)
>>>
>>> f_out = f_copy(inputs)
>>> b_out = b_copy(inputs)
>>>
>>> fb_out = fb(inputs)
>>> f_out
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[ 0.11658007],
        [-0.0704283 ],
        [-0.17762654],
        [ 0.0304627 ],
        [-0.19515464]]], dtype=float32)>
>>> b_out
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5, 1), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[-0.18902111],
        [-0.00259904],
        [ 0.23515013],
        [ 0.22268802],
        [ 0.4035125 ]]], dtype=float32)>
>>> fb_out
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 5, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[[ 0.21822408,  0.07384206],
        [ 0.0036808 , -0.0700341 ],
        [-0.11105614, -0.38493848],
        [-0.13826807, -0.12408008],
        [ 0.05806111, -0.05853282]]], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: since they are deep copy, shouldn't their output keep the same? is there any random factor there?

Answer (score 2):

The principle of BiDirectional is not as simple as you take the sum of forward and backward. The output of BiLSTM will be processed on both directions and the combination of them will be decided by tanh and sigmoid gates of LSTM. Therefore, if you divide it into 2 processes, the result can't be the same. One is for weight learning on raw bidirectional input, one is for 2 separated layers.

[image: BiDirectional Structures]

Comment: Thanks for your comments. shouldn't BiDirectional wrapper only concatenates the output of two separate layers, such as forward and backward LSTM layer? The BiDirectional does not apply `tanh` and `sigmoid` to them, right?

Comment: when I said tanh and sigmoid, I mean the gates inside LSTM not the activation function after running Bidirectional LSTM.

Comment: BiDirectional wrapper can interract with the both layer at the same time, and the output can be merged together by sum, multiply or concatenate to make use of dense features

Comment: https://keras.io/api/layers/recurrent_layers/bidirectional/
According to keras, they also use RELU in the backward layer, you can try that to verify your assumption

Answer (score 0):

It seems like to be late for this response, but I hope it would help anyone else...

Okay, Bidirectional layer in keras does behavior like merging (sum/concat etc.) two regular LSTMs, but it would not take care of initializing weights, which is why you have different outputs.

For example, you have a simple input with 3 timestamps and 2 features for each step.

```
import tensorflow as tf

unit = 1
dim = 2
timestamp = 3
inputs = tf.random.normal([1, timestamp, dim])
```

Let's have three layers: forward LSTM, backward LSTM and Bidirectional one.

```
forward_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(unit, return_sequences=True)
backward_layer = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(unit, return_sequences=True, 
                                      go_backwards=True)
fb = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(forward_layer, backward_layer=backward_layer)

forward_layer.build((None, timestamp, dim))
backward_layer.build((None, timestamp, dim))
fb.build((None, timestamp, dim))
```

Just check initialized weights and you'll see Bidirectional layer initialized a new set of weights for forward part, but used the same sets for backward part. You can finally get the same results if you reset weights accordingly.

```
a, b, c = forward_layer.get_weights()
a1, b1, c1 = backward_layer.get_weights()
a2, b2, c2 , a3, b3, c3 = fb.get_weights()

fb.set_weights([a, b, c, a1, b1, c1])

forward_layer(inputs)
array([[[ 0.0342516 ],
    [ 0.0213093 ],
    [-0.06462004]]], dtype=float32)>

backward_layer(inputs)
array([[[-0.08782256],
    [-0.16806953],
    [-0.17708375]]], dtype=float32)>

fb(inputs)
array([[[ 0.0342516 , -0.17708375],
    [ 0.0213093 , -0.16806953],
    [-0.06462004, -0.08782256]]], dtype=float32)>
```